# Swiper disable auto resize of slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swiper.js

Currently I have a div element with a height of 400px. I would like it to stay that way. However, the Swiper framework changes its settings and sets a value relative to the size of the screen (Ex: 480px). How do I disable the automatic adjustment?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid horizontal resizing, you must set `overflow: hidden` to your container (parent element of `swiper-container)`, and to avoid vertical resizing, you can add `autoHeight: true` to the properties of your slider. If your `slider-items` get too close to one another (which kind of ruins the animation) you can set the `spaceBetween` property.

I used `overflow:hidden` on the parent element in conjunction with `autoHeight` and added some additional paddings to my elements to fix my problem. Good luck.